# How to align two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have an application where I have two boxes which I have to use as landline number with the std code but i can not align two boxes side by side this is my code plese chk..

```
<div class="row">

    <label for="lbl-01"><bean:message key="tml.registration.label.landNumber"/><span class="formElementRequired">* </span> +91</label>
    <div class="phcontainer">
        <div class="phleft"><html:text property="landLineNumber" styleId="landLineNumberId" styleClass="text" maxlength="11"/></div>
        <div class="phright">yep</div>
    </div>       

    <font class="help_text">Max. 11 characters</font>
        <div class="errorDivClass"> 
        <%--<logic:messagesPresent property="landLineNumber">
                <font color="red"><html:errors property="landLineNumber" /></font>
            </logic:messagesPresent> --%>
        </div>  
</div>
```

This is my css

```
   .phcontainer {
 /*  width: 80%; */
 overflow: hidden;

 }
.phleft, .phright {
 float: left;
 /* width: 40%; */
 margin: 0 5%;
```

}

Comment: i can not align two divs side by side

Comment: Is the textbox larger than the 40% div?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/36hxcpgt/

Comment: thanks yogesh its working!! and can you help me to make a little space between them?

Answer (score 0):

remove float , and give them `display:inline-block;` also add a fiddle if u need more help

```
.phleft, .phright {
   margin:0 5%;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require?

HTML

```
<div class="div_a">
      <p>Contact Name:</p>
      <p>Peter</p>
      <p>John  </p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="Div_b">
        <p>Number:</p>
        <p>555-6052</p>
      <p>555-6021  </p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.div_a {
    color: #333;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color:#069;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left:15px;
}
.Div_b {
    color: #036;
    background-color:#333;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:175px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-top:-18px;
}
```

[Demo JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7m2dumo9/)